# possibly a slight bug in android renderscript source

Tags: android, renderscript

just looking through the [source for renderscript](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/renderscript/RenderScript.java;h=f1e5af1eb5405bcd11c9fe4061af5b4ce73c5555;hb=9df3331836144c494524d56ca3248916e02b0d3a).
I think I spotted a mistake, on line 36

```
private static final boolean LOG_ENABLED = DEBUG ? Config.LOGD : Config.LOGV;
```

Think that needs to be a double == but don't have enough coding experience to be sure.

Answer (score 7):

No, I don't think it *is* a bug. It's setting `LOG_ENABLED` to either `LOGD` or `LOGV` depending on the value of `DEBUG`.

The relevant bit is:

```
public class RenderScript {
    static final String LOG_TAG = "libRS_jni";
    private static final boolean DEBUG  = false;
    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration", "deprecation"})
    private static final boolean LOG_ENABLED = DEBUG ? Config.LOGD : Config.LOGV;
```

and that last line is *conceptually* equivalent to:

```
    private static final boolean LOG_ENABLED;
    if (DEBUG)
        LOG_ENABLED = Config.LOGD;
    else
        LOG_ENABLED = Config.LOGV;
```

In fact,

```
private static final boolean LOG_ENABLED == DEBUG ? Config.LOGD : Config.LOGV;
```

doesn't actually make sense since it means:

```
private static final boolean ((LOG_ENABLED == DEBUG)
                               ? Config.LOGD
                               : Config.LOGV);
```

which doesn't have a variable name being declared at all, just a value that should be assigned to something.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple bit of confusion about how [ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator) work in Java.  You're doing something like:

```
int i;
boolean b;
int n1=2;
int n2=3;

i = b ? n1 : n2;
```

where b can be an expression evaluating to true or false.  I used to use parenthesis around the first element to make this clear, although I just looked through some of my code and I seem to have stopped doing that now!

Comment: Its not just in Java. Most of the languages have this same syntax for ternary operators. Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: